# Execute function after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, url, redirect

I have a function that do change currency depending on chosen country. It just redirects to the same page but with different `currency` value.

Script:

```
    $("select#billing_country").change(function(){
   if($(this).val()=="UA")
   {    
       $("li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_cod").show();
       $("p#billing_last_name_field").show();
       $("p#billing_street_field").hide();
       $("p#billing__house_field").hide();
       $("p#billing_appartement_field").hide();
       $("select#billing_country").val("UA");
       $(location).attr('href', 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/?currency=UAH');

   }


   if($(this).val()=="RU")
   {
        $("li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_cod").hide();
        $("p#billing_last_name_field").hide();
        $('input:radio[name=payment_method][value=interkassa]').click();
        $("p#billing_street_field").show();
       $("p#billing__house_field").show();
       $("p#billing_appartement_field").show();
       $("select#billing_country").val("RU");
       $(location).attr('href', 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/?currency=RUB');  
    }


    else{
        $("li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_cod").hide();
        $("p#billing_last_name_field").hide();
        $('input:radio[name=payment_method][value=interkassa]').click();
        $("p#billing_street_field").show();
       $("p#billing__house_field").show();
       $("p#billing_appartement_field").show();
       $(location).attr('href', 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/?currency=USD');  
    }
    });
```

I want to do firstly redirect page than I want to give to select a value of country it has. If have selected Russia and I choose Ukraine, currency becames `UAH` but select will stay `RU`. How can I do this

Comment: You cannot execute code after redirect. You can use localStorage to save the selection

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no way to run a script on the page after the Redirect has been completed. You can only effect the page when it loads essentially. In this way you can use Server Side Scripting to set the value or you can use JS/jQuery to read the details from the URL and then effect the page after. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @mplungjan I decided to do this about it 10 minutes ago, it's a great way to write a script. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot find your select. You are trying to hack a woocommerce plugin. Then I cannot help you at all. It is not how to do this. You need to change stuff on the server

Comment: Hack wordpress plugin? I'm just trying to create a script that will change currency when I'm choosing country.

Comment: `<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select " data-qa-id="Страна" autocomplete="country" data-placeholder="Выберите страну/регион...">` 2676 string in `view-source:https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/`

Comment: @mplungjan do you know how to let select stay correct? If I change option, currency is changing but option is not. When I'm reloading page, it changes into right option. I tried to make page reload after redirection but it makes script not working correctly.

Comment: I cannot look at `https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/?currency=UAH` because it immediately redirects to /cart

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, you have to take one product in cart to have access to checkout page: https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/product-category/woman-en/body/

Comment: Ok, I did, I do not see any select there now either

Comment: @mplungjan here video when I show location of select https://youtu.be/zpEMoEYqRAk

Comment: Can you show it on the interface too?

Comment: @mplungjan it's hidden select which gives value to span with `id="select2-billing_country-container"`. So I cannot show you. You can see only `country` span on frontend

Comment: @mplungjan I've already posted answer. It works. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

```
let currencyRusON = window.location.href.includes('https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/?currency=');

if (currencyRusON == true) {
  jQuery(function ($) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var modalValue = localStorage.getItem("savedCur");
    if( modalValue ){
    location.reload(true);
    localStorage.removeItem("savedCur");
    }
}, 1000); 
});
}
jQuery(function ($) {
  
let currencies = {
  "UA": "UAH",
  "RU": "RUB",
  "BY": "RUB",
  "KZ": "RUB",
  "MD": "RUB",
  "US": "USD",
  "AU": "USD",
  "CA": "USD",
  "CN": "USD",
  "TR": "USD",
  "JP": "USD",
  "AT": "EUR",
  "AL": "EUR",
  "BE": "EUR",
  "BA": "EUR",
  "VA": "EUR",
  "GB": "EUR",
  "HU": "EUR",
  "DE": "EUR",
  "GR": "EUR",
  "DK": "EUR",
  "IE": "EUR",
  "IS": "EUR",
  "ES": "EUR",
  "IT": "EUR",
  "LV": "EUR",
  "LT": "EUR",
  "LI": "EUR",
  "LU": "EUR",
  "MC": "EUR",
  "NL": "EUR",
  "NO": "EUR",
  "PL": "EUR",
  "PT": "EUR",
  "RO": "EUR",
  "RS": "EUR",
  "SI": "EUR",
  "FI": "EUR",
  "FR": "EUR",
  "EE": "EUR",
}
let $billingCountry = $("#billing_country");
let cur = $billingCountry.val();
if (cur == "UA") {
  $("li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_cod").show();
  $("p#billing_last_name_field").show();
  $("p#billing_street_field").hide();
  $("p#billing__house_field").hide();
  $("p#billing_appartement_field").hide();
  $("tr.woocommerce-shipping-totals.shipping").show();
}

if (cur != "UA") {
  $("li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_cod").hide();
  $("p#billing_last_name_field").hide();
  $("tr.woocommerce-shipping-totals.shipping").hide();
  $('input:radio[name=payment_method][value=interkassa]').click();
  $("p#billing_street_field").show();
  $("p#billing__house_field").show();
  $("p#billing_appartement_field").show();
}

let toggle = function() {
  let cur = $billingCountry.val();
  localStorage.setItem("savedCur", cur);
  let eng = window.location.href.includes('https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/checkout-2/');
  let rus = window.location.href.includes('https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/');
  if (rus == true) {
    $(location).attr('href', 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/checkout/?currency=' + currencies[cur]);
  }
  if (eng == true) {
    $(location).attr('href', 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/checkout-2/?currency=' + currencies[cur]);
  }
}

$billingCountry.on("change", toggle);
let savedCur = localStorage.getItem("savedCur");
if (savedCur) {
  $billingCountry.val(savedCur);
}
});
```